# Parse RSS feed to json , react-native

Tags: javascript, json, xml, react-native, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse data from an RSS feed which is in xml and then make it to json. I tried using the fetch method but no luck.

Comment: Please read through [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can use the fetch api and just return the response as text, then maybe use a library like this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json to convert into json for your app.

Comment: In addition to reading what @dmulter linked, please also provide your code next time so we can help you with what might have been written wrongly in your code